# How would I pass a getParam param to another screen using react-navigation in a stateless component to fire up a graphql mutation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-component

Following the docs: [react-navigation params](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html), I'd basically do something like this (parent):

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
  itemId: 86,
  otherParam: 'anything you want here',
});
```

And then passing to the child

```
class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const itemId = navigation.getParam('itemId', 'NO-ID');
    const otherParam = navigation.getParam('otherParam', 'some default value');

    return ( (..omited for brevity)
```

EDIT:
My situation is that in one screen/container we fire up a graphql mutation that takes a phoneNumber and retrieves a code to user.
Onto the next screen I need to take this phoneNumber that the user has just inserted to fire another mutation that takes phoneNumber and code to make the authentication. I don't want to use states to do that, since there's api available on react-navigation.

Parent:

```
signInUser(phoneNumber: string) {
  const { navigation, sendCode } = this.props
  sendCode({ variables: { phoneNumber } }) // graphql mutation
  navigation.navigate('Authenticate', { phoneNumber }) // passing 
                                            // phoneNumber as param

}
```

Child:

```
export const AuthenticationCodeModal = (props: NavigationScreenProps) => {
  const {navigation} = props
  const phoneNumber = navigation.getParam(phoneNumber)
  // console.log(phoneNumber)
  // I need to get phoneNumber here and pass it as props to 
  // <AuthenticationFormContainer> which will fire up auth mutation
  return(
    <View style={styles.container} >
      <AuthenticationFormContainer/>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Sorry. But can you please explain more about what you want?

Comment: @anhtu sorry. I want to pass phoneNumber as a param to another screen. In one screen we would have the user inserting his phoneNumber and firing up a mutation to send user a smsCode, and onto the next screen we would need to get this phoneNumber that he just inserted in the previous screen and the code of the next screen by the user to make the authentication (which takes phoneNumber and code)

Answer (score 0):

It better and interesting if you use redux for task like this. Redux has a global state which can be assessed by any component

Comment: I thought of that even though I'm using apollo-link-state as a state management library. But I don't think it's a good practice to put stuff on the state like since we have a simpler way of doing it..

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a simple syntax error of the value that getParam receives, doing this fixed my problem:

```
navigation.navigate('Authenticate', { phoneNumber: {phoneNumber: phoneNumber} })
```